# How can I reference the outputs of multiple tasks with one name?

Tags: gradle

Or in other words: How do I gather outputs of multiple tasks?

I have a project with a number of tasks whose output I want to include in the distribution.
I also have a task that depends on all of them.
How can I avoid listing all the tasks?

Example `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'distribution'
}

task taskA0 {
    ...
}
task taskA1 {
    ...
}
task taskA2 {
    ...
}
task allA {
    dependsOn (taskA0, taskA1, taskA2)
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            // this works but is tedious
            from taskA0
            from taskA1
            from taskA2

            // this doesn't work, as allA doesn't have any output
            from allA
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
task allA {
    dependsOn (taskA0, taskA1, taskA2)
    outputs.files(taskA0, taskA1, taskA2) 
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from allA
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Huh, that was simpler that I expected. I somehow only looked for a way to *set* the task outputs but not *add to* them. Thanks!